# js vanilla on click delegate on tr of a table

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find on click a data attribute from the tr element of a table with the delegated click event, but it doesn't return anything, what am I wrong?

I made a fiddle to try and test

```js
document.querySelector('table#listaCar tbody').addEventListener('click', e => {
  
  if (e.target.matches(".car-item")) {
    alert(e.target.getAttribute('data-id-car'));
  }
  
});
```

```css
table#listaCar tbody tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="listaCar" class="table table-bordered table-hover bg-white">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">N. IUV</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-id-car="4140" class="car-item">
      <td>4140</td><td>TO PAY</td><td>13-05-2022</td><td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id-car="4129" class="car-item">
      <td>4129</td><td>TO PAY</td><td>12-05-2022</td><td>15</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

`e.target` is the `td`, not the `tr`.

Easiest solution is to use `.parentNode` to get the `td`'s parent: the `tr` then you can test using `matches` and get the `data` attribute as desired

```js
const tr = e.target.parentNode;
if (tr.matches(".car-item")) {
    alert(tr.getAttribute('data-id-car'));
}
```

---

```js
document.querySelector('table#listaCar tbody').addEventListener('click', e => {
    const tr = e.target.parentNode;
    if (tr.matches(".car-item")) {
        alert(tr.getAttribute('data-id-car'));
    }
});
```

```css
table#listaCar tbody tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="listaCar" class="table table-bordered table-hover bg-white">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">N. IUV</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-id-car="4140" class="car-item">
      <td>4140</td><td>TO PAY</td><td>13-05-2022</td><td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id-car="4129" class="car-item">
      <td>4129</td><td>TO PAY</td><td>12-05-2022</td><td>15</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you got the target...thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a test on the element click to see if it is a table cell (TD) and if it is grab the parent.

In my example I am looping through all the rows to apply the click.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.car-item').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let el = e.target.tagName === "TD" ? e.target.parentElement : e.target;
    alert(el.getAttribute('data-id-car'));
  });
});
```

```css
table#listaCar tbody tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="listaCar" class="table table-bordered table-hover bg-white">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">N. IUV</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-id-car="4140" class="car-item">
      <td>4140</td><td>TO PAY</td><td>13-05-2022</td><td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id-car="4129" class="car-item">
      <td>4129</td><td>TO PAY</td><td>12-05-2022</td><td>15</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```